# Box-Cox Tranformation Error: object 'x' not found

Tags: r, lambda, statistics, transform, mass-package

hopefully a relatively easy one for those more experienced than me!

Trying to perform a Box-Cox transformation using the following code:

```
fit <- lm(ABOVEGROUND_BIO ~ TREATMENT * P_LEVEL, data = MYCORRHIZAL_VARIANCE)
bc <- boxcox(fit)
lambda<-with(bc, x[which.max(y)])
MYCORRHIZAL_VARIANCE$bc <- ((x^lambda)-1/lambda)
boxplot(bc ~ TREATMENT * P_LEVEL, data = MYCORRHIZAL_VARIANCE)
```

however when I run it, I get the following error message:

```
Error: object 'x' not found. (on line 4)
```

For context, here's the str of my dataset:

```
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    24 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ TREATMENT             : Factor w/ 2 levels "Mycorrhizal",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ P_LEVEL               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Low","High": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ REP                   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ ABOVEGROUND_BIO       : num  7.5 6.8 5.3 6 6.7 7 12 12.7 12 10.2 ...
 $ BELOWGROUND_BIO       : num  3 2.4 2 4 2.7 3.6 7.9 8.8 9.5 9.2 ...
 $ ROOT_SHOOT            : num  0.4 0.35 0.38 0.67 0.4 0.51 0.66 0.69 0.79 0.9 ...
 $ ROOT_SHOOT.log        : num  -0.916 -1.05 -0.968 -0.4 -0.916 ...
 $ ABOVEGROUND_BIO.log   : num  2.01 1.92 1.67 1.79 1.9 ...
 $ ABOVEGROUND_BIO.sqrt  : num  2.74 2.61 2.3 2.45 2.59 ...
 $ ABOVEGROUND_BIO.cubert: num  1.96 1.89 1.74 1.82 1.89 ...
 $ BELOWGROUND_BIO.log   : num  1.099 0.875 0.693 1.386 0.993 ...
 $ BELOWGROUND_BIO.sqrt  : num  1.73 1.55 1.41 2 1.64 ...
 $ BELOWGROUND_BIO.cubert: num  1.44 1.34 1.26 1.59 1.39 ...
 $ TOTAL_BIO             : num  10.5 9.2 7.3 10 9.4 10.6 19.9 21.5 21.5 19.4 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   TREATMENT = col_factor(levels = c("Mycorrhizal", "Non-mycorrhizal"), ordered = FALSE, include_na = FALSE),
  ..   P_LEVEL = col_factor(levels = c("Low", "High"), ordered = FALSE, include_na = FALSE),
  ..   REP = col_integer(),
  ..   ABOVEGROUND_BIO = col_number(),
  ..   BELOWGROUND_BIO = col_number(),
  ..   ROOT_SHOOT = col_number()
  .. )
```

I understand there's no variable named bc in the MYCORRHIZAL_VARIANCE dataset, but I'm just following basic instructions given to me on performing a Box-Cox, and I guess I'm confused as to what 'x' should actually be denoted as, since I thought 'x' was being defined in line 3? Any suggestions as to how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `x` appears to be inside `bc`, try `bc$x` in line 4.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error message for that too! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately ```bc$x``` is giving back the error message ```Error: object 'x' not found```. Should I be defining 'x' or 'y' as a response or predictor variable?

I've been using the following from a handbook on how to perform the transformation, if this clears anything up?
BOXCOX TRANSFORMATION
```install.packages("MASS") # install library from web library(MASS) # load library
fit <-lm(RESPONSE~TREATMENT,data=yourdata) bc <- boxcox(fit)
lambda<-with(bc, x[which.max(y)]) yourdata$bc <- ((x^lambda)-1)/lambda) boxplot(bc ~ TREATMENT, data = yourdata)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought 'x' was being defined in line 3?

Line 3 is `lambda<-with(bc, x[which.max(y)])`. It doesn't define `x`, it defines `lambda`. It does **use** `x`, which it looks for *within* the `bc` environment. If you're using `boxcox()` from the `MASS` package, `bc` should indeed include `x` and `y` components, so `bc$x` shouldn't give you the *same* error message. I'd expect an error about the replacement lengths. Because...

`bc$x` are the potential lambda values tried by `boxcox` - you're using the default `seq(-2, 2, 1/10)`, and it would be an unlikely coincidence if your data had a multiple of 41 rows needed to not give an error when assigning 41 values to a new column.

Line 3 picks out the lambda value that maximizes the likelihood, so you shouldn't need the rest of the values in `bc` ever again. I'd expect you to use that `lambda` values to **transform your response variable**, as [that's what the Box Cox transformation is for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation). `((x^lambda)-1/lambda)` doesn't make any statistical or programmatic sense. Use this instead:

```
MYCORRHIZAL_VARIANCE$bc <- (MYCORRHIZAL_VARIANCE$ABOVEGROUND_BIO ^ lambda - 1) / lambda
```

(Note that I also corrected the parentheses. You want `(y ^ lambda - 1) / lambda`, not `(y ^ lambda) - 1 / lambda`.)